# Upload file and form data to server using AngularJS and Web API

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to upload file and form data to server using Angular and Web API.I am using the following code.

Service:

```
 App.factory('myService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        uploadFile: function (url, file) {
            return $http({
               url: url,
               method: 'POST',
               data: file,
               headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }, 
               transformRequest: angular.identity 
            });
        },
        otherFunctionHere: function (url, stuff) {
            return $http.get(url);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Controller

```
  $scope.uploadFile = function() {
      var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
      fileInput.click();
       if(fileInput.files.length === 0) return;
       var file = fileInput.files[0];
       var payload = new FormData();
       payload.append("stuff", "some string");
       payload.append("file", file);
       myService.uploadFile('/api/CsxForm/Upload', payload).then(function(response){
        }).catch(function(response){
        });
    }
```

API

```
[Route("api/CsxForm/Upload")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UploadFile(string stuff, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
         string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
         string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            //save the file
         try
         {
            file.SaveAs("//MyDrive/Folder/" + fileName + extension);
          }
         catch (IOException exc)
         {
            return Json(new { status = "error", message = exc.Message });
         }
          return Json("Uploaded");
}
```

But went I access the API, "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI". I got this as Response body. Can someone Help me fix this?? Thanks

Comment: Have you tested your endpoint from a service like Postman? If so, what response do you get?